# How to autofocus first visible input field in jquery using `alteditor`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autofocus

I am trying to autofocus every first element of modal that is triggered by datatable-alteditor. For better understanding, here is the [Datatable example.](https://luca-vercelli.github.io/DataTable-AltEditor/example/12_inline_buttons/example12.html) When I click on Add button I need `name` element field to focus. Here is the [EXAMPLE-HTML](https://github.com/KasperOlesen/DataTable-AltEditor/blob/master/example/12_inline_buttons/example12.html) and [EXAMPLE-JS](https://github.com/KasperOlesen/DataTable-AltEditor/blob/master/example/12_inline_buttons/example12.js)

I have gone through its [Github documentation](https://github.com/KasperOlesen/DataTable-AltEditor#column-modifiers-and-validation) but couldn't find any example for `autofocus`. I have tried to add `autofocus` through column options object by setting it true/false and tried to trigger through script. But nothing worked out me. Kindly please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w97qd3mz/) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please do not just point us to code linked to another website. Code on that site might change or disappear over time, leaving the question here without any context for future readers. Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77055686/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question

Comment: Thank you @Chris Barr. Edited as per your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good start however it appears that when clicking on the blue button produces an error: `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_openAddModal')"` - Please make a functioning code snippet so that the issue you want help with can be demonstrated.

Comment: As I already mentioned, you need to include `altEditor.datatable.free.js` file to get rid of those errors.

Comment: What?  Your code snippet requires me to download additional files just to make it work and reproduce your issue?  Why not just edit your snippet to include the required files. The entire point of a code snippet it so that you as a question asker can **make it easy** for someone to reproduce your issue and help you.  You are making this extremely difficult with all of this back and forth. Please just make a working demo that just shows the issue you are having.

Comment: Kindly, please don't get frustrated sir. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to include the file since it is too large. I have created `https://jsfiddle.net/w97qd3mz/`. Thank you for your time. This was my first time asking question. I will learn it gradually `@Chris Barr`

Comment: I understand what you mean, sorry if I came off a bit too harsh.  Generally though please make questions easy to answer by including everything needed directly in the question in a way that demonstrates the exact problem you are having. If your code demo is too large for StackOverflow's maximum size length then that means you have not made a **minimal** reproducible example.  Try not to copy/paste all your code, but try to reproduce the issue with the least amount of code as possible so that it's easy to focus on the exact problem.

Comment: Isn't this https://jsfiddle.net/w97qd3mz/ helpful sir.

Comment: It is helpful for showing the issue, however over 1000 lines of javascript is **a lot** to sort though just to show an issue where an input field is not getting focus. It shows the issue, but it is not the minimal amount of code needed to show this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort though your code and add this.  It feels like a bit of a hack but it does work from what I can tell

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    $(selector).find('input,select').not(':disabled,[readonly]').first().focus();
}, 500);
```

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/g29b6kep/

What I added is around line #400

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and teaching me how to post question.

Comment: May I know, why did you add `setTimeout()`. I have tried to trigger by `selector` like what you written inside `setTimeOut()`. But not worked for me. So, I would like to know the reason. Thank you!

Comment: I added that because it needed to be delayed.  Otherwise it would try to focus the input as soon as the modal opens, and it needs time to complete the modal opening animation.  See my example of **where** to put that code so that it happens after the modal opens.  There may be better ways or better places to put that, but I am not familiar with the framework and I don't want to keep sorting through 1000+ lines of javascript to find the best place to do that

Comment: Thank you! Adding `setTimeOut()` worked for me :-)